# What type of television or monitor can I connect to?

Tags: display, hdmi

What sort of input socket does my television or computer monitor need to have to be able to use it as a screen for my RP?

Will old televisions work with some sort of converter?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A television or monitor will require either an [HDMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI) input for video and audio or a [composite video cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_video) for video and a 3.5mm stereo cable for audio. If sound is not required then the minimum will be a composite video connection.

Answer (score 7):

For televisions that don't have HDMI or composite input, you can purchase an RF Modulator (Usually around $20-30 at your local RadioShack). This can take the composite output from the Raspberry Pi and turn it into a frequency that can be tuned by your television's coaxial input (usually over channel 3 or 4).

---

Source: User is former RadioShack employee. Used to sell hundreds for old people wanting to hook up DVD players to ancient televisions.

Answer (score 6):

You want an [RCA connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_connector).  Most TVs manufactured since about 1990 have them.

The video connector usually has a yellow (not red or white) jacket.

Comment: And the red and white's can be used for the audio jack

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend composite. It's *very* low resolution and jiggles like crazy! It appears you need a monitor with HDMI or DVI inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Cost effective way to connect our raspberry pi, Without any extra hardware, we can connect using vnc server,vnc client,

we need to install tight vnc server on raspberry pi and connect the raspberry pi to our computer using vnc client.

http://www.tightvnc.com/vncserver.1.php

Comment: One could argue that the computer itself is extra hardware! How easy would it be to get tight vnc server operating without connecting a display to the RPi? ie assuming you've just imaged an OS to an SD card